# SQL Server : select all rows from a column after the 1st row with matching value from the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Table1 -
ID | Name
--------
1  | Jos
2  | Tim
3  | Karl
4  | Joe
5  | Tom
```

Output I am looking for

```
Name
Tom
Jos
Tim
Karl
Joe
```

so the output should consist the matching and non-matching values, but the matching value in the first row.

I have tried something like below but I am not able to get the matching value in the first row.

```
select distinct Name
from(
SELECT Name
FROM table1
WHERE Id = 5
UNION SELECT Name
FROM table1) temp
```

Comment: What matching or non matching logic do you follow ?

Comment: matching condition is Id = 5, if you see the query which I have tried , the condition is given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select name
from your_table
order by case when id = 5 
              then 1 
              else 2 
         end, 
         id
```

Comment: Perfect!. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The @Juergen answer +1 is what I would probably use, but your union approach might even perform well, so here is how you can make it work:

```
SELECT name
FROM
(
    SELECT name, 1 AS ord FROM table1 WHERE id = 5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, 2 FROM table1 WHERE id <> 5
) t
ORDER BY ord;
```

The trick here is to introduce a computed column `ord` which keeps track of whether a name matches and should appear first.

Comment: Union instead of Union ALL is fine ? because I am getting correct output for both of them.

Comment: Hang on...your question is also showing all 5 rows.  If you want to _remove_ certain rows, then you should state the logic for that, and also update your question.

Comment: I want to select all rows , just the matching one I want in the first row.

Comment: Yes...and my answer does this.

Comment: Yes it does, what I mean is Union also does the same.

Comment: @JaydeepShil Yes...but `UNION ALL` is more efficient than `UNION`, because the former does not require checking for duplicates.  My answer is already optimal.